# "Remain" vs. "remain as"

Tags: prepositions, sentence-choice

When would you omit the "as"?

I know the following sentence can be reworded, but for the sake of an example:

> A lack of protein remains his most critical issue.
>
> A lack of protein remains as his most critical issue.

Comment: You would _always_ omit the "as" except when you have a good reason to include it in the sentence. Can you explain why you think you should normally include "as" after "remain"?

Comment: Think of **remains** as **is still**.

Answer (score 2):

There is a slight difference between the two expressions.

> A lack of protein remains his most critical issue.

This means that a lack of protein was his most critical issue, and it is still that.

> A lack of protein remains as his most critical issue.

This may mean that his most critical issue was something else, for example, dehydration, but now lack of protein is most critical.